# REST Calls to SP 2013 Foundation Calendar

Tags: rest, calendar

Is it possible to make RESTful calls to a SharePoint Calendar?  I'd like to implement Javascript code that makes a restful call to our company calendar, and if a birthday is on the current day then the code displays a birthday announcement on our SharePoint home page.  Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use the `Lists` endpoint

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CalendarListTitle')/Items
```

You can apply `$filter` on the items and pick the results you want

Comment: I must be doing something incorrectly because I'm getting a 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it' error.  Do I need to a filter after 'items' to get any information?

Comment: How are you opening this URL?

Comment: I'm just entering that url into the address bar in the browser, replacing the 'siteurl' with our site url, and 'calendarlisttitle' with the title of our calendar list.  Is this valid?

Comment: Yes that is valid.. Are you logged into the SharePoint site on the same browser? Which browser version you are using?

Comment: Yes, the same browser is able to open SharePoint.  I'm on the most recent version of chrome, Version 53.0.2785.89 m.  I must be doing something silly.

Comment: What if you try this `http://siteurl/_api/web`?

Comment: That works, but it's the unformatted XML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44768/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-alex-edwards).